# Android Studio Gradle Invalid file Manifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, configuration, android-manifest

I'm trying to build my android project on AndroidStudio version 0.4.4, but something went wrong after I touched the file build.gradle, which now looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 19
                buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

                defaultConfig {
                    minSdkVersion 9
                    targetSdkVersion 19
                    versionCode 1
                    versionName "1.0"
                }

                signingConfigs {
                    release {
                        storeFile file('somekey.jks')
                        storePassword "pass"
                        keyAlias "alias"
                        keyPassword "pass"
                    }
                }

                buildTypes {
                    release {
                        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                        runProguard false
                        debuggable false
                        jniDebugBuild false
                        zipAlign true
                        renderscriptDebugBuild false
                        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
                    }

                    debug {
                        debuggable true
                        jniDebugBuild true
                        renderscriptDebugBuild true
                    }
                }
            }

            dependencies {
                compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.1'
                compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
                compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
                compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
            }
```

It was like this before:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
}
```

Now I getting this error every time I try to run my project:

```
Throwable: Invalid file: file://C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/myprojectname/myproject/build/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Clean your project once from `Build >Clean Project` and make sure the AndroidManifest exist at the path shown in error after reBuild.

Comment: I tried that before posting, and it didn't work. But Today when opened AndroidStudio, the problem was gone...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a coincidence that as soon as I commented on your question I also ended up with same error and I resolved it my own.

```
File > Invalidate Caches/Restart
```

Solved my problem.

Comment: Next time it happens, I'll try that. Today when I opened AndroidStudio, the problem was gone.

Comment: ok accept the answer if it solves your problem too so will be useful for others.

Comment: I had to Build -> Clean Project then File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I found out it was caused, when I have an already running application followed by

Build -> Clean Project or Build -> Rebuild Project then trying to Run the project.

The solution was to terminate the running app by:

1) Go to the Android DDMS window, 6:Android.

2) Select the running App.

3) Click the X (Terminate Application).